# Deleting 100 largest files from XYZ directory

Tags: linux, file, command-line

How to delete 100 files from XYZ directory that occupy most memory from command line?

I tried to find them but could't figure out how to delete them on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the files in current directory using `ls`.
The `ls` command has an option to sort by size, which is `-S`.

`ls -S|head -10` will list the 10 largest files in the current directory.

Example:

```
for file in `ls -S|head -10`; do rm $file; done
```

Comment: This is [brittle](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in multiple ways; a robust approach is described in [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Comment: Note that this will not work, if any files have spaces (or, beware, special characters like '*') in them.